# Could someone help me to identify these characters on the screen walls

Tags: character-identification

Today I visited a garden of one of my friends and there were several screen walls with a character on each one. (The owner was absent and neither could his housekeeper read these characters.) 
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
These walls shield the cloister.
[image: 5]
The last wall shields the gate.

But still I could guess out most of them (as a native speaker). The first four are 天 地 同 和 (point out if I am wrong). By no means can I identify the last one. Hope someone can help X:D

(I recognize 酋 and 廾 up to down in the last character, but they don't look like any character I know.)

Comment: The character is 尊.

Comment: @droooze (｡･ω･｡)ﾉ♡ Ooops, but the bottom of it... sigh.

Comment: I'll write up the explanation soon, just gotta find the right references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character is 「尊」.

---

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[前](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)5.4.7
[合集6903](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=6903&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>[隸定](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%9A%B6%E5%AE%9A)
[image]</kbd>

「尊」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_%282014%29): **/*[ts]ˤu[n]/**) was originally a combination of a [*wine vessel* 「酉」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=718) and [*two hands* 「廾」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=60), indicating the meaning *(to conduct) a wine ceremony* or *ceremonial wine vessel*. From [*Etiquette and Ceremonial*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiquette_and_Ceremonial):

> 《儀禮ㆍ士冠禮》
>
> > ......側**尊**一甒醴在服北......
>
> ***Etiquette and Ceremonial:*** *Coming of age capping rites*
>
> > *...A jar of **ceremonial wine** proper at the Northern gown arrangement...*

「酉」 was later replaced with the derivative 「酋」 (also *wine vessel*).

<kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
三年壺
[集成9727](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9727&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>隸定
[image]</kbd>

Eventually, 「廾」 was replaced with [「寸」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=48) (**/*[tsʰ]ˤu[n]-s/**, *picture of hand pulse location* > *hand actions*), gaining a sound hint in addition to its semantic function.

<kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
[日甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)67背
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

---

**References:**

- 黃德寬《古文字譜系疏證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

---

In case the other characters are hard to recognise, 「地」 and 「和」 are written with variants「坨」and「龢」, respectively.